# How to get a process file name from pid, if OpenProcess() fails with ACCESS_DENIED?

Tags: windows, security, winapi

I'm trying to get a process name from its pid. User is running as Administrator, UAC enabled, not elevated.

Some system processes, like `services.exe`, have their security set up in such way that `OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION ...` fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Same result with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access right. However, I can see that [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) **can** at least list all these processes, along with their pid and file name (when running as non-elevated Administrator).

My question is, how can I do the same (get file name from pid), given that non-elevated administrator cannot follow the usual route of OpenProcess() + GetProcessImageFileName()?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried Process32First() and Process32Next() with a handle retrieved by CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()? It doesn't give you the full path but should at least let you get the file name.

Comment: Thank You Jim - that was brilliant suggestion. If anyone needs example, here's an [MSDN one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Please take into account that CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() works nearly 100x slower comparing to QueryFullProcessImageName. So, if you need to fast  and often update info about non-system processes - better to use QueryFullProcessImageName. And if you need all processes - you actually don't have other options than use slow CreateToolhelp32Snapshot

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` instead?  It requests a lower level of access that can provide at least the name of the executable.  It allows you to call `QueryFullProcessImageName` which provides the information you're looking for

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Sorry I edited just before you answered. Yes, I tried this, and it does not help. Same access denied error.

Comment: A handle of a system process opened with PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION will not allow you to call QueryFullProcessImageName. It fails with error 31 "A device attached to the system is not functioning." even when my program runs with full administrator rights (without the SE_DEBUG privilege).

Comment: Regarding the above, on what OS did you find that? With the latest builds of Windows 10 (aka "October 2018 Update"), a MediumIL process can OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION) on an Admin process and get the full executable path via `QueryFullProcessImageName`.

Comment: PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION doesn't work when passed the PID of dwm.exe in Windows 10

Answer (score 5):

You can't open system processes (more precisely, processes running under another account - in this case user SYSTEM) without `SE_DEBUG` privilege enabled for your process.
If you are running as admin, you can easily set the privilege:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131065/en-us

Comment: That article is a bit outdated. Unfortunately, you cannot get SeDebugPrivilege unless elevated (UAC).

Comment: @haimg: I googled a little but couldn't find anything on that, you got any link where it says that?

Comment: I tried that in my code... However, look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx. It says that SeDebugPrivilege is removed from a restricted token (for Administrator).