# How to get the process handle of an elevated process?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-10-seattle

With Delphi 10 Seattle, I use this code to get the handle of a process:

```
uses
  Winapi.Windows;

var
  hp: THandle;
begin
    hp := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, ProcessID);
```

This works well with all processes, both 32 bit and 64 bit.

Unfortunately, it does not work with ELEVATED PROCESSES, where it gives back **0**.

So how can I get the process handle of an elevated process?

Comment: Noy sure if it matters, but I ask anyway: Is your app running elevated or not?

Comment: You mean the app where I run this code? No. But even if I run my app elevated it gives back zero.

Comment: Ok. Then, what does GetLastError say? Ref. MSDN docs regarding return value: `If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.`

Comment: I get `Access denied`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that you cannot do this. The system said no. When you call `GetLastError` the value returned will be `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Your process does not have sufficient rights to gain `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` to a process that is elevated.

You will succeed if you make the call to `OpenProcess` when your process is elevated.

Alternatively it is plausible that you might be able to get by with lower rights than `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`. That's hard to judge since we don't know what you mean to do with this process handle. According to your comments you will pass the handle `GetProcessImageFileName` which is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217.aspx) as requiring either `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` or `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`.

Comment: I need the process handle to get the process file path with `GetProcessImageFileName`. So is there another way to get the process file path of an elevated process?

Comment: If you want the full file path then you will need to run your process elevated. This question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146498/how-to-get-a-process-file-name-from-pid-if-openprocess-fails-with-access-deni

Comment: HEUREKA!! It works when I use `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` ($1000) instead of `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION`!! I then get the full path of the elevated process with `GetProcessImageFileName`!!

Comment: That's a little surprising given the answers and comments in that other question. Anyway, that is the final paragraph of my answer.

Comment: BTW, `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` seems to be not defined in `Winapi.Windows` or anywhere else in the RTL. However, the value of `$1000` seems to be correct.

Comment: Yeah, RTL header translations are lagging. The value is documented on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684880(v=vs.85).aspx